# Retain order of values in binary matrix in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I created a binary matrix from 2 pandas columns

df:

```
ID_2  ID_1
1111  1
22222 2
33333 3
33333 4
44444 5
55555 6
55555 7
66666 8
66666 9
77777 10
77777 11
77777 12
```

Using:

```
A = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID_1')['ID_2'].astype(str)).max(level=0)
print (A)
```

This creates a matrix:

```
      22222 33333 44444 55555 66666 77777 11111
ID_2
1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
3     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
4     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
5     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

....

all fine - except the first unique value from ID_1 is placed in the last column. I need the order of the values to be to be retained as in ID_2.

Comment: looks like your code works fine. which version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reorder the columns, I think you need this:

```
A = A.reindex_axis(['11111'] + list(A.columns[:-1]), axis=1)
```

## Edit

You can do in this way:

```
 from collections import OrderedDict
 cols = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list(df['ID_2'].values)))
 cols = [str(i) for i in cols]
 A = A.reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
```

here you keep the element of the column in a ordered way(and without duplicates) and then you use them as header

Comment: That would be a nice solution - but when it comes to having multiple data sets it would be good if there was similar that would automate the reordering. Or force the order from the start.